# Duplicate products in MySQL using Paging by LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

I have a query that gets a bunch of products for a product list using ajax and infinite scorll.  If you notice at the end, it makes use of offset to "page" between lists of products, which would mean this same query is ran 3 times with different offsets ( no offset, offset 9, offset 18) for 20 products.

Now it is using order by position and is_in_stock.   The problem I am having is that position is set to 1 for all products because the admin didnt update the position to be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc for each product.

And because all positions are set to 1, the offset functionality isnt working properly, showing duplicate products on different pages of the offset.

Am I forced to have to set the position, or is there another way to do this?  Maybe I should check if the customer set the position, and if not, remove the ORDER BY position syntax?

Thoughts?

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IF((IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 1, 1, cisi.manage_stock) = 1), cisi.is_in_stock, 1) AS `is_saleable`, `cisi`.`is_in_stock` AS `inventory_in_stock` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='3'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON (cisi.product_id=e.entity_id) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` 
   ORDER BY `is_in_stock` desc, `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the position indeed, or find another way to order the products, for instance by ID (which you should set to auto_increment).